# How to hide DWR parameters appering in burp suit Or making non editable

Tags: javascript, java, dwr

In our application we are having DWR call to DAO layer for doing some DB action.

> Example call :POST /myapplication/dwr/call/plaincall/UserManager.updateUser.dwr HTTP/1.1
>
> httpSessionId=CAFFFCDF37009C2424049FF58FAE68F4.node1
> scriptSessionId=94FE7BF29DCB9C6D5078090225416EE7269
> c0-scriptName=UserManager
> c0-methodName=updateUser
> c0-id=0
> c0-param0=number:10231867
> c0-e1=number:10231867
> c0-e2=string:wf001
> c0-e3=string:001
> c0-e4=string:001
> c0-e5=string:001
> c0-e6=string:001
> c0-e7=string:
> c0-e8=null:null
> c0-param1=Object_Object:{userID:reference:c0-e1, socialTitle:reference:c0-e2, > firstName:reference:c0-e3, lastName:reference:c0-e4, userName:reference:c0-e5, > password:reference:c0-e6, email:reference:c0-e7, metadata:reference:c0-e8}
> batchId=0

This call is intercepted using burpsute and by changing the parameter values they can able to add multiple users by repeating the request.

supporting files are DWR.jar,DWR.xml and engine.js (Which calls the DAO).

Since we have no idea on how the request is framed and submitted in DWR .Is there any chance that I can restrict hacker no change values or resubmit the values.

Comment: Can Some one provide solution on this.